# Django update user profile

Tags: python, django

I am facing a lot of problems to update a user profile as customer.

Problems:

- No errors showing
- Only Email, Address and Birthday are updating
- Want to update First name and last name in user

if there is any short way to this kind of update profile, please let me know or please try to help with this code. Thank you.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class SignupUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    address = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=200)
    birthday = models.DateTimeField('Birthday')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.address


User.profile = property(lambda u: SignupUser.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from signup.models import SignupUser

class UpdateProfile(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SignupUser
        fields = ['address', 'birthday']


class UpdateUser(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email']


    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('This is not your email')

        return email
```

views.py

```
def editprofile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        profileup = UpdateProfile(request.POST or None, instance=request.user.profile)
        if profileup.is_valid():
            profileup.save()
            userup = UpdateUser(request.POST or None, instance=request.user)
            if userup.is_valid():
                user = userup.save(commit=False)
                user.first_name == request.POST['first_name']
                user.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/authority/editprofile/')
    else:
        user = request.user
        profile = user.profile
        userup = UpdateUser(instance=user)
        profileup = UpdateProfile(instance=profile)

    args = {
        'userup': userup,
        'profileup': profileup, 
    }
    return render(request, 'auth/editprofile.html', args)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add else clause after if userup.is_valid() to get more info for the error.
But i suggest you use class based view UpdateView

Comment: I with else I can update but if I will done something wrong the form is not showing any errors.